# Deja-dup - missing option for Windows Share?

Tags: kubuntu, deja-dup

I just installed deja dup through discover and had a look at backup location options but there are only 3: nextcloud, network server and local server. On my other machine, I saw there's an option for Windows Share but it's not on this one?

Deja dup ver 36.2
Kubuntu 16.10